# How to format the response from the servlet, so the dojo does not return an exception

Tags: exception, dojo, return

According to the dojo tutorial and several examples here, I am trying to send multiple multiple file help. The files to the servlet will arrive in the directory, but the dojo will return the exception

I use dojo 1.10 and  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet v3.0.1

```
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {

            if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
                try {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
                    for (FileItem item : multiparts) {
                        if (!item.isFormField()) {
                            String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                            item.write(new File("/tmp/eshop/" + File.separator + name));
                        }
                    }
                    out.print("[{uploadresult:'Upload is ok!'}]");

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    out.print("{uploadresult: 'File upload failed due to : '" + ex+"}");
                }
            } else {
                out.print("{uploadresult:'Sorry this servlet only handles file upload request.'}");

            }
             out.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
```

Error thrown :

> /dojo/v1.10/dojox/form/uploader/_HTML5.js:80 Error parsing server
>   result: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 2
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at Object.eval (/dojo/v1.10/dojox/form/uploader/_HTML5.js:76)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.  (dojo.js: 15) (anonymous) @ /dojo/v1.10/dojox/form/uploader/_HTML5.js:80
>   /dojo/v1.10/dojox/form/uploader/_HTML5.js:81  [{uploadresult: 'Upload
>   is ok!'}]

Answer (score 0):

First of all , set the response to json format

add first the `response.setContentType("application/json");`

And you thing you've to format the json correctly by adding quotes to the key  like :

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
try {

    if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
            for (FileItem item : multiparts) {
                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    item.write(new File("/tmp/eshop/" + File.separator + name));
                }
            }
            out.print("[{'uploadresult':'Upload is ok!'}]");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            out.print("{'uploadresult': 'File upload failed due to : '" + ex+"}");
        }
    } else {
        out.print("{'uploadresult':'Sorry this servlet only handles file upload request.'}");

    }
     out.close();


} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error(e);
}
```